# Alternating column colors in HTML using PHP array script

Tags: php, html, colors

What´s wrong with the following code?

```
$cores = array ("#FF0000","#FFBF00","#FFFF00","#04B404","#58FAF4","#0101DF");
foreach ($cores as $cor)
{
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td bgcolor = $cor></td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
```

---

But this code works:

```
$cores = array ("#FF0000","#FFBF00","#FFFF00","#04B404","#58FAF4","#0101DF");

for ($i=0; $i<7; $i++)
{
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td bgcolor=$cores[$i]></td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
```

Besides, it is not giving the colors in columns (which is the goal), but in rows.

Answer (score 2):

You are missing quotes around the variable:

```
foreach ($cores as $cor)
{
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td bgcolor = '$cor'></td>";       
    echo "</tr>";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Do this:

```
$colors = array("#FF0000","#FFBF00","#FFFF00","#04B404","#58FAF4","#0101DF");
$color = $colors[array_rand($colors)];
```

and pass `$color` variable to bgcolor in td

```
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td bgcolor = '$color'></td>";
echo "</tr>";
```

and it will pick up colors randomly.

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is the column, use:

```
<?php
    $cores = array ("#FF0000","#FFBF00","#FFFF00","#04B404","#58FAF4","#0101DF");
    echo "<table>";
    echo "<tr>";
    foreach ($cores as $cor)
    {
        echo "<td bgcolor= \"$cor\">1</td>";
    }
    echo "</tr>";
    echo "</table>";
?>
```